# Google Maps API 3 StreetView links without labels

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

The new feature for StreetView API 3 is that there is a label (called description) over the links (arrows of possible movement direction) on panorama.

I can turn on/off the links by the `StreetViewPanoramaOptions.linksControl` option, but I've found no way to display links without the labels, like in API 2.

I tried to intercept  `link-change` event and overwrite link definitions, but it seems that the `StreetViewPanorama.getLinks()` returns a copy of the list: there is no effect on panorama image when I change the result array.

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I tried again and find out that my original statement about the links being unmodifiable was incorrect. With the following code, I was able to erase all the labels:

```
this.displayInContainer = function( container ) {
    validatePano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
            document.getElementById(container),
            this.currentPanoramaOptions);

    var obj = this;
    google.maps.event.addListener(validatePano, 'links_changed', function() {
        var links = obj.panoObject.getLinks();
        for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ) {
            links[i].description = "";
        }
    });
}
```